# Laravel: Guard vs Session login

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, session

Sincerely apologizes if this question is a duplicate, if it is so please point me to the right directions. I couldn't find an appropriate answer anywhere.

In a scenario when I don't have to deal with password resets, what are the advantages of using `Auth::guard()` instead of normal `Session::put()/get()` as login management system in Laravel? As far as I have seen, guards use sessions to diferentiate users, and sessions can be controlled using `Session` anyway.

Wouldn't be easier to just use sessions directly instead of bothering with guards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you are not obligated to use Auth::guard() but there is plenty of features you will be missing and instead, you will have to implement some of them on your own.

You should consider that it is a common practice among Laravel developers and there will be always easier to use Laravel's out of the box implementation of the authentication system than to create your own.

If you are not forced to go with custom solution, it is always better to use the Laravel implementation and to focus on your application more instead of focusing on the framework.

Comment: I was thinking the same. Thanks for answer :)